# Difference between spark.jars vs --jars

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What is difference between `--conf spark.jars` vs `--jars` option provided on spark-submit?

Answer (score 1):

**Those two options populate the same configuration, so there is no difference between them except that `--jars` has the precedence over `--conf spark.jars`.** So if you have both `--jars` and `--conf spark.jars` set with different values, it is the `--jars` value that will be used.

### Detailed explanation

In Spark 3.1, arguments values from spark-submit are stored in [SparkSubmitArguments](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala) class. This class contains several fields, each one representing an option that can be set either using command-line arguments or using spark configuration:

```scala
var master: String = null
var deployMode: String = null
...
var jars: String = null
...
val sparkProperties: HashMap[String, String] = new HashMap[String, String]()
...
```

Those fields are initialized with `null` or with empty collection. They are populated later in the class with this code snippet:

```scala
// Set parameters from command line arguments
parse(args.asJava)

// Populate `sparkProperties` map from properties file
mergeDefaultSparkProperties()
// Remove keys that don't start with "spark." from `sparkProperties`.
ignoreNonSparkProperties()
// Use `sparkProperties` map along with env vars to fill in any missing parameters
loadEnvironmentArguments()
```

The first step is to parse all the arguments from command line and to populate fields accordingly with `parse(args.asJava)`. We pass the parsing part and look into how the fields are populated. It is done in `handle` method:

```scala
override protected def handle(opt: String, value: String): Boolean = {
  opt match {
    case NAME =>
      name = value
    ...
    case JARS =>
      jars = Utils.resolveURIs(value)
    ...
    case CONF =>
      val (confName, confValue) = SparkSubmitUtils.parseSparkConfProperty(value)
        sparkProperties(confName) = confValue
    ...
```

So value of `--jars` argument is set to `jars` field, and value of `--conf` argument is added to `sparkProperties` field map.

Once the arguments parsed, the `sparkProperties` is used to to fill the missing parameters with the method `loadEnvironmentArguments`:

```scala
private def loadEnvironmentArguments(): Unit = {
  master = Option(master).orElse(sparkProperties.get("spark.master")).orElse(env.get("MASTER")).orNull
  ...
  jars = Option(jars).orElse(sparkProperties.get(config.JARS.key)).orNull
  ...
```

For each field of `SparkSubmitArguments` class, this method checks if the field had been filled using parsed arguments, and only if it is not the case, looks into `sparkProperties` field map to fill the void.

**So `--jars` and `--conf spark.jars` fill the same field `jars` in `SparkSubmitArguments` class, the only difference is that `--jars` option value overrides `--conf spark.jars` option value**